# Validating solution to PDE using integral transforms

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals, contour-integration, integral-transforms

I'm trying to obtain the analytical solution of a Fokker-Planck PDE, which the solution is a probability density function, and then use this to find the mean of some quantity in the paper. The [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2099835?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) has a solution which they say can be found via [Mehler-Fock transform.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler%E2%80%93Fock_transform) Their solution which I am trying to obtain reads

$$P_{\varepsilon}(L,u) = \frac{e^{-\varepsilon^2sL/4}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}(\varepsilon^2sL)^{\frac32}}\int_{u}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-x^2/(\varepsilon^2sL)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{(x)}-\cosh{(u)}}}dx.$$

I obtain a different solution to this one.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$
The equation in the paper reads
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P_\varepsilon}{\partial L} = \varepsilon^2s\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\bigg[(u^2-1)\frac{\partial P_\varepsilon}{\partial u}\bigg], \quad P_\varepsilon(L=0,u) = \delta(u-1).
\end{align}
This is a $1d$ Fokker-Planck equation, where $P_\varepsilon(L,u)$ is a probability density for some diffusion Markov process. To solve this equation, note that the right hand side is simply a Legendre differential equation. Denote the legendre function of the first kind via
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{du}(u^2-1)\frac{d}{du}P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u) = -\bigg(\mu^2+\frac14\bigg)P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u),
\end{align}
which has an integral representation
\begin{align}
 P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\cosh{(\pi\mu)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(\mu\tau)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{(\tau)}+u}}d\tau.
\end{align}
Now use the Mehler-Fock transform. The Mehler-Fock transform of an integrble function $f$ defined on $[1,\infty)$ is the function $\check f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ where
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\mu) = \int_{1}^{\infty}f(u) P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u)\,du,
\end{align}
with inverse transform
\begin{align}
 f(u) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\check{f}(\mu)\mu\tanh{(\mu\pi)}P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u)\,d\mu.
\end{align}
Applying the Mehler-Fock transform to the PDF $P_\varepsilon(L,u)$ gives
\begin{align}
 \check p(L,\mu) = \int_{1}^{\infty}p(L,u)P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u)du.
\end{align}
Taking a partial derivative in $L$ gives
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial\check p}{\partial L}(L,\mu) = \varepsilon^2s\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\bigg[(u^2-1)\frac{\partial p}{\partial u}(L,u)\bigg]P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u)du.
\end{align}
Integrating twice more by parts gives
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial\check p}{\partial L}(L,\mu) = \varepsilon^2s\int_{1}^{\infty}p(L,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\bigg[(u^2-1)\frac{\partial P_{-\frac12+i\mu}}{\partial u}(u)\bigg]du.
\end{align}
Using the ODE $(2)$ which satisfies the Legendre function, the Mehler-Fock transform satisfies the ODE
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial \check p}{\partial L}(L,\mu) = -\varepsilon^2s\bigg(\mu^2+\frac14\bigg)\check p(L,\mu), \quad \check p(L=0,\mu) = 1.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
 \check p(L,\mu) = \exp{\bigg(-\bigg(\mu^2+\frac14\bigg)L\varepsilon^2s\bigg)}.
\end{align}
Hence, the solution to $(1)$ is
\begin{align}\nonumber
 P_\varepsilon(L,u) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\mu\tanh{(\mu\pi)}P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u)\exp{\bigg(-\bigg(\mu^2+\frac14\bigg)L\varepsilon^2s\bigg)}d\mu \\
 &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\mu\tanh{(\mu\pi)}P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(u) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\cosh{(\pi\mu)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(\mu\tau)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{(\tau)}+u}} \\
&\times\exp{\bigg(-\bigg(\mu^2+\frac14\bigg)L\varepsilon^2s\bigg)}d\tau d\mu.
\end{align}

This paper claims to have a solution

$$P_{\varepsilon}(L,u) = \frac{e^{-\varepsilon^2sL/4}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}(\varepsilon^2sL)^{\frac32}}\int_{u}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-x^2/(\varepsilon^2sL)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{(x)}-\cosh{(u)}}}dx.$$
Here I have computed my solution vs theirs, for varying parameter $L\in[1,10]$ and fixed $\varepsilon^2s$

[image]

Clearly they do not agree.

$\textbf{My second question}$ is how they use this solution to find a mean value via

\begin{align}\mathbb{E(R)} &= \int_{1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\bigg)P_{\varepsilon}(L,u)du \\
&= \frac{e^{(-\varepsilon^2sL/4)}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}(\varepsilon^2Ls)^{\frac32}}\int_{1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\bigg)\int_{u}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-x^2/(4\varepsilon^2sL)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{(x)}-\cosh{(u)}}}dxdu
\end{align}

$\textbf{AND then reduce this expression to read}$

$$\mathbb{E(R)}=1-\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\varepsilon^2sL}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2e^{-x^2}}{\cosh{(\sqrt{\varepsilon^2sL}x)}}dx,$$
since it's easy to see asymptotically that they behave differently. I'm looking for help in either of these questions. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Any suggestions? I can link the paper if that would help but this is all the information given.

Comment: I would be interested to see the link to the paper.

Comment: @ThomasL I've added a link. The equation in question starts at (3.9) on page 5.

Comment: @ThomasL I've added some numerical plots. The solutions don't agree. Something strange is going on here. It's highly cited so I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: thanks for your info. I tried a couple of transformations (substitutions), but could not get any closer to the required formula.
I noticed that the function is symmetrical to 0 in regards to x, but it does not really help. I highly doubt this is a one step integration.
Based on your feedback, I give up at that point, thanks.